# Jquery scripts not working in Wordpress, tried multiple enqueue methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've searched through similar questions, but didn't find an answer yet.

On my Wordpress [dev site](http://tsdevtest.com/teahouse/) using the Genesis framework, I tried using the following jquery scripts: [smoothscroll.js](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/) and Dynamic to top by Matt Verone (both the WP plugin version and manually). Neither works. I've used both of these on WP and non-WP sites successfully.

I enqueued both smoothscroll.js and the dynamic to top scripts (when using it manually), easing.js and jquery.ui.totop.min.js via the following method in functions.php.

```
function tm_scripts()
{       
    wp_register_script( 'easing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/easing.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_register_script( 'smoothscroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/smoothscroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_register_script( 'jquery.ui.totop.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/jquery.ui.totop.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_register_script( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'easing' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smoothscroll' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.ui.totop.min' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tm_scripts' );
```

They appear in the footer when I view the code.

I then tried both leaving jquery to load via wp and the following jquery enqueue method from CSS Tricks:

```
 if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "tm_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function tm_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
}
```

No luck. The only other plugins I'm using are Contact Form 7 and Akismet. I feel like there is a conflict somewhere, just not sure what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using boilerplate is a good way to beat JS conflicts and clean requests, you should try. However, nice website.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Thanks @jeromeM. Yeah, I use boilerplate on my non-wp sites. Should have with this one.

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors when I used the dynamic to top plugin. However, when I enqueue all the scripts (smoothscroll.js, easing.js, ...totop.min.js, and main.js) I'm getting an error on main.js which contains `$(document).ready(function() { $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' }); });` The error says "$ is not a function."

Comment: `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, by calling `$.noConflict()` before enqueuing the rest of your scripts, you can return control of `$` to jQuery.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Thanks. Nothing seems to be working. I've now scrapped everything and installed the wp jQuery Smooth Scroll plugin. Doesn't work either. Perhaps it's a Genesis thing? Amy inquiring on their forums.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS-tricks code wasn't working for me either, but this is

```
add_action( 'init', 'jquery_register' );
function jquery_register() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' ), false, null, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
}
```

Or any other jquery version...